# how to redirect the pages to www.abc.com if user enter abc.com in codeigniter in .htaccess file

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    hob
    RewriteRule ^aboutus/?$ $1/pqr$2 [R=301,L]
    #RewriteRule aboutus http://www.work-interactive.com/sectors/ [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

How to redirect the pages to **www.abc.com** if user enter **abc.com** in URL in  codeigniter in `.htaccess` file.

I have many pages say **www.abc/xyx.com**  if user visit this page as **abc/xyz.com** ,it should be go as **www.abc/xyz.com**.
I want to do it through `.htaccess` file in codeigniter file.
    How to do using `.htaccess` file 
    I want to edit it through `.htaccess` file in  codeigniter.

If possible what is the other way to solve it.
I have many pages if I click it should append **www** before any url.

Answer (score 0):

U can add this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Bye

Answer (score 0):

try this one hope so it will helpful for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```